# work with button in form without submit form jsp

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I am using two buttons in `<form>`. one for submit form and other for add categories to textfield.

```
<button id="catadd" class="btn-default" onclick="me()">+ Add Category</button> 
<button name="submitcreate" id="submitcreate" type="submit" class="btn-default">
```

categories add to textfield using JavaScript. `onclick="me()"` for that. 
but when i click on `catadd` button form submit too.

how stop it.

Comment: When posting use the back-tick character to indicate code. Two asterisks indicates bold, not code.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the `type` attribute to `button`

```
<form>
<button type="button">click me for some js logic</button>
<button>I am a submit by default !</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

A button with no type attribute acts as type="submit", and will attempt to submit form data when clicked.

So, the simple solution of your query would be to specify the type of the "categories add" button like:
`<button id="catadd" class="btn-default" onclick="me()">+ Add Category</button>`

More details here: https://dev.to/clairecodes/why-its-important-to-give-your-html-button-a-type-58k9